# QiskitError: 'No statevector for experiment

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-state, qiskit, programming, graph-states

This is the code that I have used. Why can't i use get_statevecto when i use quantum computer. I got a state_vector when i have used qasm_simulator.

```
qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq_5_yorktown') 
fidelitycount = 0
shots = 1
for i in range(shots):
    num_qubits = 5
    adj_matrix_fcg = np.ones((num_qubits,num_qubits),dtype=int)
    circuit_fcg_5 = qiskit.circuit.library.GraphState(adj_matrix_fcg)
    sv2 = execute(circuit_fcg_5, qcomp).result().get_statevector(circuit_fcg_5)
    #fidelity = qiskit.quantum_info.state_fidelity(sv1)
    #fidelitycount += fidelity

print(sv2)
```

and this is the error

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When running on real backends you can't get a statevector since you can't return the quantum state of the device, only get measurement outcomes. The `get_statevector` method on the `Result` class only works if the backend (in this case a simulator) returns a statevector after executing the circuit.

That being said you can however try to use quantum tomography to reconstruct the state. You can see examples in the tutorial on how to do this here:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/noise/8_tomography.ipynb

Comment: Thanks. My aim was to create a graph state using a quantum simulator and device to verify the state fidelity. Is there any way to do that?